# Insert multiple images with title

Tags: php, html

I need to insert multiple images with ad name every row. I am unable to insert ad name. I fail to modify the php code. There is no problem to insert multiple images. But problem comes when try to insert ad name with images. Plz help.

HTML

```
<form action="posting_ad_imagec.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Ad Title: <input type="text" id="ad_name" name="ad_name[]"/>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    $dir='ad/data/img/';

    if( isset( $_POST['submit'], $_FILES['files'] ) ) {

        $uploaded=array();
        $ad_names = $_POST["ad_name"];
        $sql = 'insert into `full texts` set `img_name` = ?, `img_type` = ?, `img_size` = ?, `ad_name` = ?';
        $stmt = $connection->prepare( $sql );


        if( $stmt ){

            $stmt->bind_param( 'ssss', $name, $type, $size, $ad_name);

            foreach( $_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name ) {
                if( !empty( $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i] ) ) {

                    $name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                    $size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
                    $type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
                    $tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
                    $ad_name = $ad_names[$i];


                    if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ){
                        $bytes = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $dir.$name );
                        if( $bytes ){
                            $status = $stmt->execute();
                            $uploaded[]=$status && $bytes ? $name : false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if( !empty( $uploaded ) ){
                $_SESSION['s']=sprintf("%d images successfully saved", count( $uploaded ) );
                header('Location: posting_ad_image.php');
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hey, at first check if your getting value(s) in your `$ad_names`.

Comment: Might try: `name="ad_name[]"` -> `name="ad_name"` and `$ad_name = $_POST["ad_name"]` (singular instead of plural) then trash `$ad_name = $ad_names[$i];`

Comment: @Ultimater Thank you so much. Your suggestion helped me to enter all images with `ad_name` at once. But now the  problem comes **only the first letter of ad_name enters into database** not full name.

Comment: Make sure you deleted `$ad_name = $ad_names[$i];` you don't want the `[$i]` there or it will be first character.

Comment: @Ultimater Thank you again. I deleted [$i] and my problem solved.One more question if you kindly answer me.. same images are not inserted into directory. How to create dynamic folder with `ad_name` into here `$dir='ad/data/img/'`?

Comment: First off. if you want this relative to the PHP file, you should proceed it with a `__DIR__` like so: `$dir = __DIR__.'/ad/data/img/';` Get in the habit of this or it will be relative to the working directory, meaning the PHP file used as the entry point, which you might move later and mess things up, or a call to chdir could mess things up. As far as creating the directory dynamically, you could do: `if(!file_exists($dir) || !is_dir($dir))mkdir($dir, 0777, true);` the third parameter to mkdir allows recursive creation of directories if multiple need to be created along the way.

Comment: @Ultimater You are great. Life saviour. No more query now but one more request, If you answer my question, I would accept you and also the question would be with answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Change `name="ad_name[]"` to `name="ad_name"` (no more brackets)
Step 2: Change `$ad_names = $_POST["ad_name"];` to `$ad_name = $_POST["ad_name"]` (singular)
Step 3: Trash `$ad_name = $ad_names[$i];` (no longer needed)